# Using Javascript to override image CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the CSS of all images on a webpage with Javascript. I want to add the CSS

```
Max-width:100%;
```

Some of the images don't have id tags so I can't use the `getElementById()` method.

Comment: Why not just add an "img" rule in CSS?  Why does it have to be JavaScript, in other words?

Comment: Allow me to introduce you to [`getElementsByTagName('img')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)

Comment: What @Pointy said. If you're trying to toggle between applying and not applying a "max-width:100%" rule to all images, toggle a `expandedimgs` class on a container that houses all of your desired images, and write a CSS rule for `#container.expandedimgs img { max-width: 100%; } `

Comment: I have not been able to get getElementsByTagName('img') to edit any CSS. Also I don't have access to the website. I'm injecting javascript on a mobile app.

Comment: -1 for no research effort

Comment: @AquaMorph it doesn't "edit CSS", it returns a NodeList of all the `<img>` elements in the DOM.

Comment: @Pointy well that will not help me

Comment: @AquaMorph Yes. You should write a rule in your stylesheet, as Pointy suggested earlier.

Comment: @AquaMorph - Please show the code that you have tried that doesn't work. We will be able to help you better if we have a starting point. It might make more sense to you too.

Comment: @AquaMorph ???  Have you seen Olaf Dietsche's answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) instead

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; ++i) {
    imgs[i].style.maxWidth = '100%';
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCX4S/)

Comment: This answers the question the OP is asking, so +1 for that, but I suspect it is not the question the OP needs answered.

Comment: Probably not. Hopefully, he will say so then.

Comment: This worked I just had a typing error that a repeated when I tried to find answers earlier

Answer (score 2):

Just set it to the `img` tag itself in your CSS:

```
img {
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

That would apply the style to all `<img>` tags in your HTML.

Comment: This works +1 but see my answer for a jquery script.

Comment: I don't have access to the website. I'm injecting javascript on a mobile app.

Comment: Okay, that's a key bit of missing information.   :D   Olaf's answer is a good JS solution, that being said, unless you have dynamic interactions that force you to us a JS-based approach to changing the style, the handling styling with CSS is always the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

you may also target them by class

```
.class img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

This is little more focused

or use it for all images in the document by just using

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

you can use jQuery as well and use

```
$(document).load()
```

Check out jQuery website for more references

Answer (score -1):

This will apply for all your images.

```
$('img').css({"max-width" : "100%"});
```

Really you cant do that... See jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7e2zW/